# How can I check the array of radio name button if it is not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have dynamice adding of radio button and this radio button is array named

I want to make sure that the user selected 1 radio button in each radio array

Thank you in advance

```js
$(function() {
  function addMore() {
    for (var i = 0; i < dynamic_range; i++) {

      $('.container_div').append(
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<div class="input-group">' +
        '<ul>' +
        '<li><input type="radio" name="playergroup' + i + '[]" class="form-control"></li>' +
        '<li><input type="radio" name="playergroup' + i + '[]" class="form-control"></li>' +
        '<li><input type="radio" name="playergroup' + i + '[]" class="form-control"></li>' +
        '<li><input type="radio" name="playergroup' + i + '[]" class="form-control"></li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'
      );
    }

  }

  $('#save').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    for (var i = 0; i < dynamic_range; i++) {
      if (!$("input[name='playergroup[i]']:checked").val()) {
        console.log("radio group is not check");
        return false;

      }
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <div class="container_div"></div>
  <button id="save">Save</save>
                         </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You html and jquery does not match.

html: `<input type="radio" name="playergroup'+i+'[]" class="form-control">`

jquery is looking for: `name='playergroup[i]'` but `i` is not inside the `[]` in your html

Solution : `$("input[name*='playergroup" + i + "']:checked")`;

**Demo***

```js
$(function() {


  function addMore() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

      $('.container_div').append(
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<div class="input-group">' +
        '<ul>' +
        '<li><input type="radio" name="playergroup' + i + '[]" class="form-control"></li>' +
        '<li><input type="radio" name="playergroup' + i + '[]" class="form-control"></li>' +
        '<li><input type="radio" name="playergroup' + i + '[]" class="form-control"></li>' +
        '<li><input type="radio" name="playergroup' + i + '[]" class="form-control"></li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'
      );
    }

  }


  addMore()

  $('#save').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      if (!$("input[name*='playergroup" + i + "']:checked").val()) {
        console.log("radio group is not check");
        return false;

      }
    }




  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <div class="container_div"></div>

  <button id="save">Save</save>
                     </form>
```